# RethinkDB: conditional upsert (only if particular fields are matched)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rethinkdb

I know [rethinkDB's insert()](http://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/insert/) has an upsert option. Eg, from the docs:

```
rethinkdb.table('marvel').insert(
  { superhero: 'Iron Man', superpower: 'Arc Reactor' },
  {upsert: true, return_vals: true}
).run(conn, callback)
```

But say there **might** be existing record for `{superhero: 'Iron Man'}` with an incorrect or out of date superpower, and I wanted to either insert `{ superhero: 'Iron Man', superpower: 'Arc Reactor' }` or update any existing `{superhero: 'Iron Man'}` record?

In short: how can I upsert so that existing records are updated only if particular fields are matched?

**Edit:** Seems like this is done with .replace():

Here's [the important bit from the replace() docs:](http://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/insert/)

> You can have new documents inserted if you do a point-replace on a key
>   that isn't in the table

I'm not sure what 'point-replace' means - but I assume it just means replace.

```
var latestDoc = { superhero: 'Iron Man', superpower: 'Arc Reactor' }
var mergeOrCreate = function(existingDoc) {
  if ( existingDoc ) {
    return existingDoc.merge(latestDoc)
  } else {
    return latestDoc
  }
}
rethinkdb.table('marvel')
  .filter({ superhero: 'Iron Man'})
  .replace(mergeOrCreate),
).run(conn, callback)
```

However in testing, the 'mergeOrCreate' function is being given another function, rather than an actual doc or a cursor, as an argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first code block is the answer to your first question. However, it assumes that `superhero` is the primary key for your table.

You can set the primary key of a table when creating it:

```
r.tableCreate('marvel', {primaryKey: 'superhero'}).run(conn, cb)
```

Your second code block has two mistakes.

First, the mergeOrCreate function does not work because `if` statements are evaluated client-side. You must use `r.branch` to create the equivalent of an `if` statements:

```
var mergeOrCreate = function(existingDoc) {
  return r.branch(existingDoc,    /* if */
    existingDoc.merge(latestDoc), /* then */
    latestDoc)                    /* else */
}
```

Second, `get` does not support the same syntax as `filter`. Its argument should be the value of the primary key. If the primary key is `superhero`, then:

```
r.table('marvel')
  .get('Iron Man')
```

Finally, if `superhero` is not the primary key, you have to write a different kind of query. There could be zero, one or many documents with the same `superhero`. Here is one way to write it:

```
r.table('marvel')
  .insert(
   r.table('marvel')
     .filter({ superhero: 'Iron Man' })
     .coerceTo('array')
     .do(function(docs){
        return r.branch(
          docs,
          docs.merge(latestDoc),
          latestDoc)
        }),
   { upsert: true })
  .run(conn, cb);
```

Note that because this query depends on more than one document, it is not atomic.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mind if I ask you a couple of questions? Should conditional upserts always be done with insert & the upsert option?

Comment: No, like you noticed, replace can be used too. A point replace is a replace following a get.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to to an atomic conditional upsert? Eg, if any document matches, update the first match, if not, create the document?

Comment: Also: is insert or replace preferable for this purpose? Sorry for all the questions but I couldn't find any pointers in the docs.

Comment: No. Atomic operations in RethinkDB can only depend on and modify single documents.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I meant with a single document. Ignore anything else that matches (or err), just the first result.